# Hamburger button is not displaying in Confluence 5.1.1 instance. How do I get it to display?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, nav, confluence

The hamburger button is not displaying in our Confluence 5.1.1 dev instance. Anyone know how I get it to display?

Note: Also running RefinedWiki Original Theme as the global site theme—but the specific space where the hamburger button needs to display is NOT using the RefinedWiki Original Theme / IS using the Confluence default theme.

Thanks for ideas.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have confluence linked to other applications. To do this, you'll have to navigate to t he administration console. Go to edit -> administration -> site administration. Log in with administrator credentials, and then scroll all the way down to the bottom of the left-hand menu. There should be a link, under the Administration heading, which says "Application Links." If you click that you can then add application links.

The hamburger button won't display until you have at least one application linked to confluence.

[image: Site Administration]

[image: Application Links]